# of vs for grammar

Tags: grammar, prepositions, for

In this sentence

the British government on Saturday accused Russia *of* seeking to replace Ukraine's government with a pro-Moscow administration.

Can I use "for" instead of "of"?
such as :

the British government on Saturday accused Russia *for* seeking to replace Ukraine's government with a pro-Moscow administration.

I am not quite sure why I need use "of" in this sentence. should I study the proposition?
Can someone explain to me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, "accused" in this case can't be paired with the preposition "for". When "accused" is followed by a description of the accusation, you have to use "accused of", for example: "accused of a crime". Some verbs get paired with certain prepositions but not others. "Accused" get paired with "of", whereas "blame", for example, gets paired with "for": "they blamed Russia for the events in Ukraine." Maybe someone can answer and explain the historical reason for why "accuse" got paired with "of" and not "for", all I know is that it's a convention at this point, almost like a set phrase.

Comment: No. You ***accuse** someone **of** doing something*. Also ***suspect** them **of** doing it* (only there you're more likely to say you ***suspect** [that] **they did it***). On the other hand, you ***blame** them **for** doing it*.